# Does Trello provide a way to identify who created a card?

Tags: trello

The api docs made it seem like the answer was no, but I couldn't tell.  Is there a way to find all the Trello cards I created on a board or set of boards or across all boards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the author of the card using `actions`, like this:

```
Trello.get('/cards/CARD_ID_HERE/actions?action_memberCreator_fields')
```

It is under the arguments for **GET /1/cards/[card id or shortlink]** here: https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#get-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink

You can also get a list of all your cards like this:

```
Trello.get('/members/me/cards')
```

and use the field `idBoard` to filter only cards for specific board.

Comment: That's helpful.  It sounds like the way to find all the cards I created is to first iterate over _all_ cards and then filter in the client based on the results of calling /1/cards/[id] on each card.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you export the card to JSON you can find a trace of the actions on the card. Under `share and more` -> Export JSON.

Wich has the following url:

```
<a class="js-export-json" href="/card/<id>/url-friendly-name-of-the-card.json">Export JSON</a>
```

This makes a call `GET https://trello.com/card/<id>/url-friendly-name-of-the-card.json`

In the Json you will look for the action with `type: "createCard"`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a userscript which adds the creation date and the creator name and account link to the Trello card.
You could install it from my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/almaceleste/userscripts) or from [OpenUserJS.org](https://openuserjs.org/scripts/almaceleste/Trello_card_details)