# Is there a way in Trello to automatically display the card creator?

Tags: trello

I would like Trello cards to, by default, show the creator's username.

The Custom Fields power-up allows for a user-editable text field which is displayed on the card front. Trello's Butler allows for automated filling-in of Custom Fields. However, it's unclear if there's a Butler action to fetch the username, which is the break in the chain.

[Does Trello provide a way to identify who created a card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467839/does-trello-provide-a-way-to-identify-who-created-a-card) shows how to grab the username from an API query, but that doesn't help from inside the interface.

Answer (score 1):

I have a board that I use to track my current projects and requests.  I got tired of seeing cards appear and having no idea who added them.
Using Butler, I created a rule that uses the variable @{username} to add a member that creates a card to the card they created.

```
when a card is added to the board by anyone except me, move the card to the top of the list "Open Requests," and add member @{username} to the card.
```

There are a bunch of [variables](https://help.trello.com/article/1157-variables)
you can use when writing rules.  The Butler is pretty nifty.
[1](https://help.trello.com/article/1157-variables)

Comment: What is Butler?  Oh nevermind, I see that this is what Trello calls their "Automation"